# Honda Fit moulding near trunk gasket is lifting

Tags: interior

I got my car back from some shop work to remediate flooding (of the car).  Seats were removed, carpet and electrical on the floor were replaced.  It's been about 2 weeks that I got it back after about 1.5 months in the shop (most of that waiting for the replacement carpet).

I noticed this past weekend a lifting of some moulding around the trunk door gasket.  Never saw that before.  It possible that it has nothing to do with the flood remediation work, and I don't feel that I have grounds to suggest that it is related.  I think I may just bring it into the (Honda) shop and see what they can do.  If they decide that it is a result of the remediation work (without my suggesting it), then fine.
[image]

Short of getting Honda to deal with this, can anyone suggest what might cause this?  Is there a simple way to "reseat" the moulding?  Simply pushing it back into place doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plastic piece is held in by clips that should press fit - if not, they may have broken off when the part was removed. New clips are very cheap, but take it to the dealer anyway. It looks like the rubber seal around the rear hatch has been pinched by that piece; releasing the seal may fix the problem (try to pry it out with your fingers - tools may piece the rubber), and allow you to push the trim piece back into place.

Comment: OK, thanks, Pete.  I don't know if they had to remove that moulding in the course of their work, but like I said, I'll roll with what they say.  I'll close-out this thread with the result once I've been able to follow through.

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, unpinching the seal doesn't allow the trim to be pushed back into place.  The dealer did say that it was likely removed and reassembled in the course of the flood remediation.  The clips have been ordered, and one of them is taking some time to come.  Thanks!